# Reference existing data when deserializing Java objects?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, serialization, jackson

My object graph consists of Hibernate entities. Now most of the objects don't exist in the new database. However some do. So my object is like this:

```
Class MyObject{ 
  Set<B> bset;
  Set<C> cset; 
}
```

The items in `bset` need to be instantiated and persisted after deserialization. However, the items in `cset` already exist in the new database, so I don't want new instances created. What is the best way to tell Jackson I know how to find references to these? Right now I am thinking about using a custom serializer / deserializer for `cset`, which will serialize it by creating an object with the database ID, and then will deserialize it by pulling the appropriate objects out of the database.

This is kind of complicated and I am hoping there is a simpler solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why serialize a full representation of `C` if you're throwing most of it out and only using the ID for a lookup? Will you be updating the database with the deserialized values?

Comment: I don't want to serialize a full representation of C, but I have to somehow get the entity out of the database when I am deserializing. That is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. There are three things I needed:

1. A JsonCreator to take the entityManager, and the id to return an object

   ```
   @JsonCreator
   @IgnoredMethod
   public static UiElement findById(@JacksonInject EntityManager entityManager, @JsonProperty("id") int id) {
       return entityManager.find(UiElement.class, id);
   }
   ```
2. A JsonValue getter to return an object with only the id

   ```
   @JsonValue
   @Transient
   public Map<String,Integer> getJsonObject(){
       HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
       map.put("id", getId());
       return map;
   }
   ```
3. The entity manager needed to be injected into the ObjectMapper

   ```
   //entitymanager for creating any static data based entities
   InjectableValues injects = new InjectableValues.Std().addValue(EntityManager.class, entityManager);
   mapper.setInjectableValues(injects);
   ```

Comment: Sorry a about the code formatting...something is buggy. I can't fix it.